# Custom Electron Session Path

Tags: javascript, electron, nightmare

I am using Nightmarejs which is using Electron.

I want to change the path of where the Electron `webPreferences partitions` location (the directory where it was being saved). By default it is being saved at `~/.config/Electron/Partitions`.

I can't find anything in Nightmarejs documentation. So I tried looking up the [`Sessions` module of Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/session.md) but still I can't find a way to change the directory path.

Or is it even possible to change the Electron path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to change the paths in electron https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetpathname

Then to do that in nightmarejs you need to add it as an option in initializing your nightmarejs here https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#paths

I guess this is the answer to it.